# Libreoffice Calc: date string to date/time values

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I need to extract a 'date string' as separate columns representing date/time data.

```
 | A                        | B                 | C
-+--------------------------+-------------------+-----------------
1| Datetime String          | Date Value        | Time Value
2| Sat 09 Sep 2017 20:00 PM | =DATEVALUE(A2)    | =TIMEVALUE(A2)
```

The above functions `DATEVALUE` and `TIMEVALUE` return errors. I'm at a bit of a loss at the moment.

Comment: Is the value in A2 a string or a number with a number format?

Comment: However looking through the code it seems that your format does not correspond to a valid date or time number format anyway. So based on a quick reading of the DATEVALUE function's source code there is no chance to recognize the format as a date or time anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like the date string is fixed width, so use this formula for cell B2, which builds a date string in `YYYY-MMM-DD` format and then converts with DATEVALUE.

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A2,12,4) & "-" & MID(A2,8,3) & "-" & MID(A2,5,2))
```

The formula for cell C2 only needs to extract the time, which is already in a suitable format.

```
=TIMEVALUE(MID(A2,17,5))
```

Then go to Format -> Cells, and format B2 as a date and C2 as a time.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much.

Comment: See also: https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/calc-another-text-to-date-question/65054/7

Answer (score 2):

You could try `=MID(A2,1,FIND(":",A2)-4)` for the Date Value, and `=MID(A2,FIND(":",A2)-2,8)` for the Time Value.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet but upvoted it to help you on your way with reputation. I ticked the other answer because it 1) worked and 2) was more thorough (included the tip on formatting the cells).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else comes across [Cater Allen](https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.caterallen.co.uk)'s new export format: `25Dec2020` (i.e. `DDMMMYYYY`) that isn't recognised during CSV import:

`=DATEVALUE(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A2,6,4))&"-"&MID(A2,3,3)&"-"&NUMBERVALUE(MID(A2,1,2)))` will turn it into a proper date that [YNAB](https://www.youneedabudget.com/) can recognise.

Thanks for the question and other answers that helped me get there neatly.